# How to interpret the legend using the Flannery method with the size assistant in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I've tried to use the data defined override with the Size Assistant as follows
Scale Method Flannery.
I'd like to know how this method is working and how can we read the legend generated automatically by QGIS (see figure ):

[image]

---

```
Data defined override
Active: yes   (ctrl|right-click toggles)
Expected input:
double [>= 0.0]
Valid input types:
string, int, double
Current definition (expression):
coalesce(scale_exp("fieldA", 2.11, 3.52, 1, 15, 1), 0)
```

---

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @SWS! If you open up the **Field Calculator** and search for `scale_exp` in the search bar above the function window, it will give you the parameters, description of each parameters and an example as to how this function works :)

Comment: how can we read the legend?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the numbers in the legend, take a quick look at the code that was generated by the **size assistant**.

```
coalesce(scale_exp("fieldA", 2.11, 3.52, 1, 15, 1), 0)
```

the key here is **scale_exp**, this is an exponential scale. From the function help in the expression calculator

```
Transforms a given value from an input domain to an output range using an exponential curve. This function can be used to ease values in or out of the specified output range.

Syntax
scale_exp(val, domain_min, domain_max, range_min, range_max, exponent)
```

So your values are between 2.11 and 3.52, and will be converted into an area between 1 and 15 using an [exponential curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function).

I never looked at Flannery before, but it appears to be related to optimising the size of the circle for human perception. (We're not very good at judging the relative areas of circles, even when their areas are in correct proportion. Flannery attempts to correct for that.)

See [this post](https://makingmaps.net/2007/08/28/perceptual-scaling-of-map-symbols/) for more background.

> It looks as if the values on the legend correspond to your original values, not the scaled values (those were used to calculate the size of the circle).

The **coalesce** function around it means that nulls are treated as zero, so those will not show up

Comment: How would one change the categories? Or can't it be edited as a result of the scale_exp? I have a dataset with values ranging from 1 to 500 with the majority of the attributes holding values between 1 and 100. As such I would like to change the categories to 1, 10, 25, 100, 500. Is this possible at all with the siza assistant?